# Filling an outer horn in a quasicategory when the first edge or the last edge is an equivalence

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories

I convinced myself some time ago that the following holds: given an outer horn in a quasicategory, if the first or last edge (the map $0\to 1$ or $n-1\to n$) is an equivalence then the horn has a filler. I have not reasoned with quasicategories in quite a while so I don't remember how the argument goes. I am therefore looking for a quick argument or a reference that I can cite.
This argument implies formally that a cube in an $\infty$-category, which has an initial or terminal edge that is an equivalence, is commutative if and only if its faces are. If there is a direct argument for this I would also be happy.

Comment: I have often seen this being referred to by Joyal's lifting theorem. A reference is 32.17 of https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~rezk/quasicats.pdf